# How to find all symbols clashes (referenced and unreferenced symbols )between two libraries linked to the same application?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

How to forcefully link all symbols of a static library to an application at link time in gcc?

I am trying to create an application by linking two static libraries. Both these libraries may have some symbols which may have the same name. I want to find all such symbols and rename them in one of the libraries.

But, I find that unreferences functions are eliminated and hence I am unable to find all the symbols which may be colliding. Is there a way to force gcc to link all symbols (referenced and unreferenced) from both the static libs thereby finding colliding symbols?

Or is there any other way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just use the `nm` command ([link](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm)) on each library?  `nm` should list all the symbols and then you can just compare the output of `nm` for each library.